# How to inflate LinearLayout in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-support-library, inflate

I want to inflate a `LinearLayout` into a fragment in the "onCreateView" method. But I have always the same error:

```
"android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment"
```

I am using the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` in a `"libs"` folder.

Main activity:

```
public class GeofranceDeptActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dept);

    }
}
```

The main xml file `dept`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="dauran.geofrance.DeptFragment"
            android:id="@+id/depts" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
            </fragment>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/detailsdept" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The class for the fragment `DeptFragment`:

```
public class DeptFragment extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener{

    Context mContext = getActivity();

    boolean mDualPane;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
              return null;
            }

    return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.dept_fragment, container, false);
        }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
        ................etc
```

The xml file `dept_fragment` that I want to inflate :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/targetDeptImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/region_france_grand" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cacheDeptImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/region_france_grand" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sDepartement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/targetImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `Logcat`:

```
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dauran.geofrance/dauran.geofrance.GeofranceDeptActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at dauran.geofrance.GeofranceDeptActivity.onCreate(GeofranceDeptActivity.java:10)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    ... 11 more
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment dauran.geofrance.DeptFragment did not create a view.
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:293)
06-26 19:02:27.940: E/AndroidRuntime(11993):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Logcat` probably says more then *android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment*(check below to see if you don't have an instantiation exception, maybe you could add the full exception?). After looking at your code I would assume that your `DeptFragment` isn't situated in the `dauran.geofrance` package and because of this android can't find it.

Also, there is no need to test for `null` the `container` parameter:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dept_fragment, container, false);
}
```

Also, I don't see the need for wrapping the `RelativeLayout` with a `LinearLayout` in the `R.layout.deptfragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/targetDeptImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/region_france_grand" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cacheDeptImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/region_france_grand" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sDepartement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/targetImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added the logcat I have

Comment: @user1298799 Did you make the changes from my answer and then run again the app? Do you get the same error? Also how exactly does this error appears: do you simply start the app and the exception is thrown, or you do other stuff besides what you've added in the question?

Comment: It's OK now. I just remove the unnecessary LinearLayout and the test on the container null. Thank you very much for your help.